# better way to catch Nonetype in xml parsing in python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, parsing, xpath

I need to get the strings in each table div of the table . There is a pattern it follow i.e `<td><p> <strong>text</strong></p></td>` except the last td which has `<td><p> <span><strong>text</strong></span></p></td>` .
If i keep my logic same to extract the text i get error for the last td i.e AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text .

```
import urllib2
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
import string
import csv

req_headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safar/537.36'
    }
cimb_extra_url = u"http://www.cimbbank.com.sg/index.php?ch=sg_per_st&pg=sg_per_st_inv&ac=14&tpt=cimb_sg"
request = urllib2.Request(cimb_extra_url, None, req_headers)
page = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
table_root = etree.fromstring(page, parser)
main_table = table_root.xpath("//table[@bordercolor='#FFFFFF']")[0]
all_tr = main_table.findall("tbody/tr")
for tr_itr in xrange(1,len(all_tr)):
    all_td = all_tr[tr_itr].findall("td")
    print tr_itr
    for td_itr in xrange(1,len(all_td)):
        current_td = all_td[td_itr].find('p')
        try:
            print all_td[td_itr].find('p').find('strong').text
        except Exception:
            print all_td[td_itr].find('p').find('span').find('strong').text
```

Currently i am using try and except to catch this part , is there a better way to catch this Nonetype in xml ?

Thanks

Comment: why wouldn't you use a xpath to find `p//strong/text()` on the `<td>` element

Comment: @AnttiHaapala i guess you meant `all_td[td_itr].xpath('.//p//strong/text()') `, this works , but i was more interested in catching NoneType attribute . Thanks

Comment: why not use beautifulSoup?

Answer (score 1):

With lxml, you can also use [ElementPath](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elementpath), and in your case with the `p//strong` XPath expression:

```
...
for tr_itr in xrange(1,len(all_tr)):
    all_td = all_tr[tr_itr].findall("td")
    print tr_itr
    for td_itr in xrange(1,len(all_td)):
        current_td = all_td[td_itr].find('p')
        print all_td[td_itr].find('p//strong').text
```